# Storing persistent information about items in view

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, qt5

I've my own view based directly on `QAbstractItemView`.
Generally speaking I need to store some information about particular model's item.

So in my view I have a map from `QModelIndex` to struct describing partical item.
Then I use those data mostly on view's `paintEvent`.

The problem is, that QModelIndex is not persistent, it may get outdated.
So when rows are inserted or removed from model, some `QModelIndex` may become invalid and I should not relay on them.

How then can I build relation between item in model and some decoration data I use in view?

`QPersistentModelIndex` seems to be proper tool for such things, however I'm aware of its performance (my model and view may be huge).

Another problem with `QPersistentModelIndex` is that it probably should not be used as map's key (as it is in my case) as it may (and will) change and make map inconsistent.

I've took a look at Qt's implementation of QTreeView and QListView to see how they deal rows removal/insertion, but it seems they simply drop all the data.

So at this point I cannot see any easy way to solve my problem.

Comment: I am almost certain that you do not want to implement your own view.

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: @lpapp: could you explain?

Comment: If you actually want to create your own view, maybe you should not use QAbstractItemModel, but just create something that fits your needs better instead. QAbstractItemModel is designed to be usable with all Qt views at the same time, and even for that purpose it seems to be utterly complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely use a `QPersistentModelIndex` as a <s>map or</s> hash key.
Even if the underlying QModelIndex changes, the "persistent" part ensure that all the `QPersistentModelIndex` are kept up to date while preserving their identities, i.e `operator ==` and `qHash()` return consistent values.

That being said, you should not store data about the index in your view. The data are supposed to be stored by the model.
And this seems to be how its done in Qt classes: views are making a lot of calls to `QAbstractItemModel::data()`.

The only data that I would deem worthy to be stored in the view is "cache data", i.e values that are:

- not directly provided by the model
- require heavy computation to be calculated from the model's data
- specific to the view

If any of these 3 conditions is not met, my personal preference would be to store the data in the model.

---

### Edit

Contrary to my original answer, you cannot safely use `QPersistentModelIndex` as a `QMap` key.

The reason is that `QMap` uses `operator <` for inserting and finding data.

The issue here is that `bool QPersistentModelIndex::operator<(const QPersistentModelIndex &other) const` is just a proxy to `bool QModelIndex::operator<(const QModelIndex &other) const` which compares indexes by row and column.
This means that the sort order of `QPersistentModelIndex` is **not persistent** and will change when indexes are moved in the model.

However, `QMap` is not aware that the sort order has changed. And at this point searching a value inside a `QMap<QPersistentModelIndex, T>` is just as broken as doing binary search on an unsorted array.

Note that this issue is not limited to `QMap`, it affects all containers which are based on the ordering of the keys like `std::map`. However, containers that do not rely on ordering (`QHash`, `std::unordered_map`, ...) are not affected.

Comment: I match the 3rd case. What I'm still worrying about is the performance of such solution. However I'll give it a try and perform profiling. I think it would be great for qt models to have an unique id for items. What would be very efficient. My first guess was that `QModelIndex::internalId()` is the solution, but tests proved it is not (at least not for some of the standard Qt models)

Comment: @PatrickParker `QPersistentModelIndex` are updateds when the model is updated. If a row is inserted before, then the value returned by `QPersistentModelIndex::row()` will increase by one. If a row is deleted before, it will decrease by one. If the "cell" referenced by the `QPersistentModelIndex` is deleted, `QPersistentModelIndex::isValid()` will return false.

Comment: @PatrickParker `QPersistentModelIndex` are implemented using `QPersistentModelIndexData`. 2 instances of `QPersistentModelIndex` referencing the same "cell" will share the same instance of `QPersistentModelIndexData`. 2 `QPersistentModelIndex` are equals if and only if  they use the same `QPersistentModelIndexData *` internally. The qHash of a `QPersistentModelIndex` is just the qHash of its internal `QPersistentModelIndexData *`.

Comment: @PatrickParker I just edited my answer. I spent some time digging in Qt code and running tests, and `QPersistentModelIndex` must not be used as `QMap` keys. Their ordering is based on the row/column which will change when the model changes, silently breaking the `QMap` internal ordering.

Comment: @BenjaminT thanks for confirming that. So if we add the stipulation that `moveRows` is not called or implemented (meaning row numbers change only due to remove or insert) perhaps it would be safe then? I suppose we'd need to further guarantee that indexes be removed from the QMap during `rowsAboutToBeRemoved`, since a removed row could jump our `QPersistentModelIndex` key to logical row number `-1` -- also in violation of presumed sort order.

Comment: @PatrickParker You need to stipulate that index order must not change: no row change, no column change, no internal pointer change and no model change (if that means anything). So you cannot move rows, but you also cannot insert/remove anywhere but at the end. And yes, removing them from the QMap before the actual remove.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to map some data to some model items, make each item store its data. This involves using a delegate for painting and not relying on `QAbstractItemView` paint event.

Let's have a simple stateful class, to represent our item data, and let's make it a new citizen in Qt meta-object system, using the [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) macro.

```
#include <QMetaType>
class ItemData
{
public:
    ItemData() = default;
    ItemData(int d) : _data(d){}
    int data() const { return _data; }
    void paint(QPainter *painter, QRect rect);
private:
    int _data;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ItemData)
```

Now the delegate, a very simple one, indeed:

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
class ItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    // ...
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    // ...
};
```

The delegate paint method, is where things happens:

```
void ItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.data().canConvert<ItemData>())
    {
        ItemData itemdata = qvariant_cast<ItemData>(index.data());
        itemdata.paint(painter, option.rect);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Here we can use the model index for what it is meant: retrieve the item data. Our item can paint itself, though. Let it paint some circles, according to its internal state:

```
void ItemData::paint(QPainter *painter, QRect rect)
{
    QRect r(rect.left() + 2, rect.top() + 2, rect.height() - 4, rect.height() - 4);
    for(int i=0; i<_data; ++i)
    {
        painter->drawEllipse(r);
        r.moveLeft(r.left() + rect.height() + 2);
    }
}
```

In a more flexible design, data is decoupled from rendering, so the `ItemData` class have no `paint` method and painting is performed by the delegate itself:

```
void ItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.data().canConvert<ItemData>())
    {
        ItemData itemdata = qvariant_cast<ItemData>(index.data());
        //itemdata.paint(painter, option.rect);
        QRect rect = option.rect;
        QRect r(rect.left() + 2, rect.top() + 2, rect.height() - 4, rect.height() - 4);
        for(int i=0; i<itemdata.data(); ++i)
        {
            painter->drawEllipse(r);
            r.moveLeft(r.left() + rect.height() + 2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

This way, we can implement and then choose different delegates for different views, yet keeping a single consistent model and share it among them.

Using delegate and data in a item-based widget like `QListWidget` is straightforward.
In a form constructor:

```
ui->listWidget->setItemDelegate(new ItemDelegate());
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    QListWidgetItem * item = new QListWidgetItem();
    item->setData(0, QVariant::fromValue(ItemData(i + 1)));
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

Not so different in a model-based one, though: instead of setting data to items, data is set to the model, again using `QVariant::fromValue`.

Comment: Your solution is interesting however it requires me to 'override' DisplayRole (or any other role in model). Data I wanna store are view specific and I wouldn't like to destroy data provided by model (which can be used in another view). I'd love store them in a custom role, but how can I be 100% I do not overwrite model specific data (as some models use custom roles - QFileSystemModel for example). Sorry for being fussy ;)

Comment: @Michal create a subclass of QIdentityProxyModel and override userdata role there. your view can be the sole user and consumer of this proxy.