# Why a QPersistentModelIndex cannot be stored in one of the QStandardItemModel's items?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstandarditemmodel

### Background

In my model I have to keep in one item's data, a reference to another item.

The documentation of [`QPersistentModelIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html#details) says:

> A `QPersistentModelIndex` is a model index that can be stored by an application, and later used to access information in a model.

[`QStandardItemModel::setData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setData) accepts `QVariant` as a value, which in turn can be [constructed from `QPersistentModelIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-43), so I am able to write something like this:

```
...
auto *model = new QStandardItemModel();
auto *referencedItem = new QStandardItem("Test");
auto *item = new QStandardItem();

model->appendRow(referencedItem);
item->setData(QPersistentModelIndex(referencedItem->index()), Qt::UserRole);

// the next line prints "Test"
qDebug() << item->data(Qt::UserRole).toPersistentModelIndex().data().toString();
...
```

The code compiles and prints:

> Test

The accepted answers to another topics, e.g. [Storing persistent information about items in view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48882501/5366641) and [How to update a QTableView cell with a QCombobox selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48106206/5366641), also suggest the use of `QPersistentModelIndex`.

### Problem

The documentation of `QPersistentModelIndex` also says:

> **Note:** You cannot store a [`QStandardItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html)'s `QPersistentModelIndex` in one of the model's items.

Does this mean, that using `QPersistentModelIndex` like in the code above, i.e.:

```
item->setData(QPersistentModelIndex(referencedItem->index()), Qt::UserRole);
```

is wrong and why this should not be done?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with removing rows and trying to update things in those rows which were being removed.

Comment: OK, but how should this affect the persistent index, stored in the data? It could have been any `QVariant` afterall. Why should this matter?

Comment: The difference is, normal QVariants don't have a special update mechanism that is tied internally to the way Qt handles model row removals. The memory address of every QPersistentModelIndex has to be maintained somewhere and invoked during the row removal process to update its row numbers. So, if it were to be deleted at an unexpected time, that could cause a crash. Again, I am just speculating. It is entirely possible that comment is outdated. Check the source.

Comment: @PatrickParker, I have tried moving items around in the model and deleting items from the model. It didn't crashed yet and the indices are updated correctly. So, I am looking further for a possible reason.

Comment: did you try simultaneously deleting a range of several rows that contain self-referencing persistent model index? if that works then I am stumped as well. I have not digged into the source.

Comment: In my model there are not any self referencing persistent model indices. An item may only store the index of another item.